# Polymer 1.0 - What is replacement of paper-shadow?

Tags: polymer

After Google I/O 2015 announce Polymer version 1.0 I found that paper-shadow is disappear. So I try to find a replacement for this element.

Who know what element can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [paper-material](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-material).

Comment: It's work, but something happen, I style `:host` to `background-color: white;` it's not apply. So I put `class` attribute to make it `white` again. I want to know why it don't work after change to `paper-material`? Is it involve with something about styling on Polymer 1.0

Answer (score 0):

I think they deprecated it in 2.0 favour of [paper-styles](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-styles).